# Infinitesimal generator for non-Markov process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I have read that the infinitesimal generator for a Markov process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ we define the generator $A$ by

$$Af(x) := \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))-f(x)}{t} $$

whenever the limit exists in $(C_{\infty},\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$. The definition implies that
$$\mathbb E[Af(X)]=0$$ if $X$ is the stationary distribution.

I want to know why the definition is limited to Markov processes and not defined for a general stochastic process?

Answer (score 5):

Just my guess, it's because Markov property makes the infinitesimal generator identify the **entire** process. This is surprising because the infinitesimal generator is defined only at the neighborhood of $s=0$.

By the definition, the infinitesimal generator is similar to the derivative in calculus, i.e. we want to introduce some derivative-like notion of stochastic process. A straightforward approach to develop it is to define it for all time $s\ge0$. This may be tentatively defined for all $s\ge0$ as:
$$
A_sf(x) = \lim_{t\to0} \frac{ \mathbb{E}\left\lbrack f(X_{s+t}) \middle\vert \mathcal{F}_{s} \right\rbrack - f(x)}{t},
$$
where $X_s = x$ and $\mathcal{F}_s$ is the filtration generated by $X_s$.

However, if $\{X_s\}_{s\ge0}$ has the Markov property (and it leads the time-homogeneity), we only need to define it at (the neighborhood of) $s=0$ with the initial value $x$. In fact, for all $s\ge0$,
$$
\begin{align}
A_s(x)
&:= \lim_{t\to0} \frac{ \mathbb{E}\left\lbrack f(X_{s+t}) \middle\vert \mathcal{F}_{s} \right\rbrack - f(x)}{t} \\
&= \lim_{t\to0} \frac{ \mathbb{E}\left\lbrack f(X_{s+t}) \middle\vert X_s = x \right\rbrack - f(x)}{t} \quad (\because \text{Markov property}) \\
&= \lim_{t\to0} \frac{ \mathbb{E}\left\lbrack f(X_t) \middle\vert X_0 = x \right\rbrack - f(x)}{t} \quad (\because \text{time-homogeneity}) \\
&= A_0f(x).
\end{align}
$$

In other word, if $\{X_s\}_{s\ge0}$ has the Markov property, the derivative-like notion at $t=0$, so called the infinitesimal generator of $\{X_s\}_{s\ge0}$, determines, identifies or generates the **entire** process with initial value $x$.